# What is a good way of filling a form in ExtJS by code, and fire the events for each component as if they were filled by the user?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the project I'm working on, I have forms I sometimes have to fill by code.

Let's say I have two comboboxes : combo1 and combo2. They are both required by default (allowBlank : false). On combo1's select event, I set combo2's allowBlank property to true and clear it. Everything's good so far, while user is filling the form.

When I use combo1's setValue method, it doesn't trigger the select event, so combo2 is still required when I don't want it to be. What is a good way to solve this problem? Should I fire the events manually after setting values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to trigger the events manually.

No UI events are triggered with JavaScript. This is to prevent endless loops and other undesired side-effects while interacting with the page programmatically.

In ExtJS, there is `component.fireEvent(...)` for that purpose.